# for-loop with user defined array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop

My current projects is suppose to get user input for *participants* (**integer**) and *new participants* (**integer** ), define an array for individual inputs (*participants* and *new* *participants*), then loop through code asking for the name of the participant or new participant. Though, in my first for-loop (And second if my code would reach there) it starts by asking "Name #1:" , then after input starts bugging out very bad and exits program. I think the problem is in the pointers, but here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int dV = 1;

int students;
int newStud;

cout << "Enter number of participants : ";
cin >> students;
system("CLS");

cout << "Please enter the number of new participants: ";
cin >> newStud;
system("CLS");

while(newStud > students)
{
    cout << "You entered a number greater than the overall participants!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of new participants: ";
    cin >> newStud;
    system("CLS");
}

int *pointer1 = new int[students]; //Pointer to an array of size students(Variable)
int *pointer2 = new int[newStud]; //Pointer to an array of size newStud(Variable)


for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
{
    cout << "Name #" << dV << ": ";
    cin >> pointer1[i]; //ERROR HERE: After first input, program text blinks a few times then exits     
    system("PAUSE"); //Used for debugging
    system("CLS"); 
    dV++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < newStud; i++)
{
    cout << "New name #" << dV << ": ";
    cin >> pointer2[i];
    system("CLS");
    dV++;

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless all your students are secret agents, or live in the world of THX-1138, they have names, not numbers.  Change the type you store the names in.

The problem you're seeing is that you want to read an integer from `cin` but you're giving it text.  This sets the error bit on the stream, so all subsequent inputs after that will fail until it is reset.